# Is "Were you in time?" the right question?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, simple-past

For example,

> Hey, you went a few minutes ago, but haven't given me a call yet. Were you in time for your job?

Is this the right question to ask?

Answer (score 2):

Was that the *right* question to ask? It depends.

> Were you **in time** for work?

Might imply: Did you get to work before your boss saw you were missing? Or whether you got to your work place sufficiently *in time* to do your tasks.

> Were you **on time** for work?

To be "on time" means not to arrive late. If my job starts at 8.30 a.m. and I get to my office desk at 8.29 a.m. I am *on time*.

If I arrive at my desk precisely at 8.30 a.m. then I would say

> I arrived **on** the dot

Answer (score 1):

'Were you in time'?, or 'Were you on time'? are both normal familiar idioms. There is a tiny difference in the circumstances in which they are used, but they are virtually interchangeable.

In the example you need to say 'on time for work'. We tend to speak of 'work, rather than one's 'job', when it come to being 'on time' or 'late'.

'Being 'in time', is more appropriately used where the thing for which one is speaking could happen loosely at roughly a particular time. For example, 'Where you in time to see John before he left?'

Trains and buses arrive 'on time' or 'late'. You need to be 'on time' to catch one, but if you are unaware of the time it leaves, provided you arrive 'in time' you will be alright.

You will always be understood if you use the wrong one, but it is the sort of misuse that merely highlights when a person is not a native speaker.

Americans may have different thoughts to me on this matter.

Comment: I like the train example. Being pedantic though, I'd say that you need to be *in time* to make a train — you could have been *on time*, but the train left early!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to say "were you **on** time?". I don't know of anyone to phrase it "were you in time".